# how to get send email functionality in android using HTML & JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: android, email, cordova

I have a button named Send Email, when i click on the button it should open a page to compose mail.I want to get this using html and js.Can anyone please help me to get this functionality. Some good links and examples are really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function in phonegap to send an email. But you can do it by customizing your phonegap plugin by Phonegap Web Intent. Read this [tutorial](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/)